# how to display different footer navbar content based on screen size

Tags: bootstrap-4

based on screen size I would like to display different footer content.

for large screens I display:

```
<nav class="navbar p-0">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">left content</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">center content</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">right content</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

for small screens I would like to display:

```
<nav class="navbar p-0">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">left content</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

probably I missed something in the docs at

- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

but there has to be a way to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @NishiJain who pointed me into the right direction I was able to find a pretty simple (and dry) solution:

```
<nav class="navbar p-0">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">left content</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto d-none d-lg-flex">
        <li class="nav-item">center content</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto d-none d-lg-flex">
        <li class="nav-item">right content</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

full docs regarding display utilities: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Answer (score 3):

You can use bootstrap responsive utilities classes.

For large screen display

```
<nav class="navbar p-0 hidden-xs-down">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">left content</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">center content</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">right content</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

for small screens

```
<nav class="navbar p-0 hidden-md-up">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">left content</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

For more information refer: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/

Comment: thanks. unfortunately `.hidden-*` classes have been dropped -> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#utilities -> I tried to use https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/ but did not get it to work...

Comment: found a fix. thanks for pointing me into the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar p-0 d-none d-md-block">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">left content</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">center content</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">right content</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="navbar p-0 d-block d-md-none">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">left content</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The class `d-none/block` should work fine for this case.

Take a look on his own doc [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#common-display-values).